# Receives "-bash: /usr/bin/hamachi: No such file or directory" when using command "hamachi --version" after hamachi has been installed

Tags: networking, pi-4, raspberry-pi-os, vpn, packages

I have followed the guides put forth in the following forum when trying to install hamachi manually on raspberry Pi OS 64-bit on a Raspberry Pi 4 8gb:

[Installing Hamachi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10110/installing-hamachi/53234#53234)

Whenever I try to use the command `hamachi` it gives me an error, saying:

`sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/hamachi: No such file or directory`

Whereas when I go to `/usr/bin/hamachi` and do `ls` I find that `hamachi` is listed. Here is a link to a copy of the full export:
https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/07eTn9gBYmNRlR6ArXGWGnW_A#User/bin
The color it's listed in shows that the Hamachi file listed is a symbolic link. I have tried to install and uninstall hamachi a number of different ways, so it could be that the link is now broken.

I can use the command stated in the readme file to start/stop/etc. the server, however, it also states an error/notice:

```
pi-dragon6000@raspberrypi:~ $ /etc/init.d/logmein-hamachi start
Starting LogMeIn Hamachi VPN tunneling engine logmein-hamachi
starting - success
/etc/init.d/logmein-hamachi: 46: /opt/logmein-hamachi/bin/hamachid: not found
```

When I try to do the `hamachi --version` command shown before but instead capitalized, I get a slightly different result:

```
pi-dragon6000@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo Hamachi --version
sudo: Hamachi: command not found
```

The same happens when I use the `login` argument:

```
pi-dragon6000@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo Hamachi login
sudo: Hamachi: command not found
```

This is a section of a terminal session where I try to install hamachi:

```
pi-dragon6000@raspberrypi:~/logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.203-armel $ sudo ./uninstall.sh
Stopping LogMeIn Hamachi engine ..
Stopping LogMeIn Hamachi VPN tunneling engine logmein-hamachihamachid: no process found

stopping - success
Removing LogMeIn Hamachi service ..
Removing LogMeIn Hamachi symlink ..
Removing files from /opt/logmein-hamachi ..
LogMeIn Hamachi is removed.
pi-dragon6000@raspberrypi:~/logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.203-armel $ sudo ./install.sh
Copying files into /opt/logmein-hamachi ..
Creating LogMeIn Hamachi symlink ..
Creating TunTap ..
mknod: /dev/net/tun: File exists
Installing LogMeIn Hamachi service ..
Starting LogMeIn Hamachi service ..
Starting LogMeIn Hamachi VPN tunneling engine logmein-hamachi
starting - success
/etc/init.d/logmein-hamachi: 46: /opt/logmein-hamachi/bin/hamachid: not found
LogMeIn Hamachi is installed. See README for what to do next.
pi-dragon6000@raspberrypi:~/logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.203-armel $ /etc/init.d/logmein-hamachi start
Starting LogMeIn Hamachi VPN tunneling engine logmein-hamachi
starting - success
/etc/init.d/logmein-hamachi: 46: /opt/logmein-hamachi/bin/hamachid: not found
pi-dragon6000@raspberrypi:~/logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.203-armel $ sudo hamachi login
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/hamachi: No such file or directory
pi-dragon6000@raspberrypi:~/logmein-hamachi-2.1.0.203-armel $ ls
CHANGES  dnsup     hamachi-init  LICENSE  Release_notes.rtf
dnsdown  hamachid  install.sh    README   uninstall.sh
```

Hopefully all this information helps!

What should I do?

***Edit: I went to the place where I think the symbolic link was likely pointing: `~/opt/logmein-hamachi/bin` and found the following files in that folder:`dnsdown  dnsup  hamachid`.
When trying to run `hamachid` it gave another "does not exist error". So perhaps it's not a problem with the link-file, but rather a problem with the actual `hamachid` file.

Answer (score 0):

Hello **WitherDragon6000**, any progress on this issue? I am facing the exact same. I posted answer because I am not able to contact you other way.

Ok, so for me only worked to go with 32 bit OS.