# Unable to use time lapse feature with RaspiStill

Tags: camera

For some reason RaspiStill has lost some of its functionality.  When I tried to use the `-tl` argument it doesn't produce any photos and seems to hang up.

The full command I am running is:

```
raspistill -rot 180 -q 80  -w 1920 -h 1080 -t 300000 -tl 999999   -o /media/64GB/www/timelapse/timelapse_%d.jpg
```

I am able to take photos without the `-tl`  I have tried adjusting the amount `tl` is, I have also tried adding the `-n` flag.

For example:

```
raspistill -rot 180 -q 82 -w 1920 -h 1080 -n -t 120000 -tl 999999 -o /media/64GB/www/timelapse/photo_%d.jpg
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The `-tl` timelapse option says to take a picture every `<t>` milliseconds.  By using  `999999` you're specifying to take a picture every ~999 seconds.  Try using a smaller number such as `1000` to take a picture every second.

I do know that there are issues that cause the camera to hang such as specifying a very-long exposure, see https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/issues/33 for more details on that issue.