# Start "getty" service in Raspbian to Login to Pi using Serial console

Tags: raspbian, serial-console

I am following [this tutorial](http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection) to setup login using UART serial console.

When I run `screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200` from my Ubuntu desktop, the serial port opens and if I restart Pi, I am able to see the entire boot message.

After booting up, the login command is shown, but I am not able to type anything. I double checked my connection and restart Pi a couple of times, but I am still facing the same problem.

I was doing a web search and found [this thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=19186) in the Raspberry Pi forum.

The solution is to start the `getty@ttyUSBx.service`, but the command given there is only for Arch Linux.

Now my question is what is the equivalent of the following command in Raspbian

`systemctl start getty@ttyUSBx.service`

Comment: 1) Did you uncomment the "T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100" line in /etc/inittab file? 2) Did you plugged Ground wire of usb serial device?

Comment: @gurcanozturk Yes to both your questions

Comment: can you update your question with contents of cmdline.txt file ? Also please output of "dmesg |grep tty" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it seems that there was some problem in the USB to Serial convertor that I was using.

Things have started to work again.