# Stream (or Airplay) between 2 Raspberry Pi's?

Tags: raspbmc, streaming-video

I have 2 Raspberry Pi's, 1 is on one side of the apartment, the other is on the other side of the building.  The fist is connected via wire, the other via wireless, all - of course - connected to the same network.
One Pi has a USB harddrive connected, the other has nothing connected.
They both run RaspBMC.

Last week I tried to see a movie from one Pi on the other Pi using uPNP to read the other Pi's library, but it was a little laggy, sometimes the screen stopped to buffer.
Is there a way to stream from one Pi to the other ?  Like smart streaming, based on connectionspeed - like Silverlight does or AirPlay seems to do ?

Comment: I'd just share the video-files themselves over the network. Just use NFS of SAMBA to share the files.

Comment: That's basically what I dith using uPNP to view the video... but that was way to slow... that's why I want to have one Pi to act as Streaming server and the other as Streaming client.

Comment: Did you use the "Share libraries using UPnP" option? I'm not that familiar with upnp/dlna. I know DLNA sometimes does transcoding. I think that NFS is more lightweight, and will result in better performance. Are the Pis connected via WiFi?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... but yes, I'm using now "Share libraries using uPnP"... it works like a charm... though, I guess some movies are encoded in a special way, so that decoding itself is fast enough, but the wifi on the bedroom pi isn't fast enough... or something like that... but it general, and if the wifi doesn't time out, it works perfectly.