# Connect RPi to Ad Hoc network

Tags: wifi

We want to control the RPi from a distance using a laptop and a GUI.

Our idea is to do SSH tunneling. We want to do this on an ad hoc network from a windows 7 laptop.

The RPi can connect with the wifi dongle to our network but can't connect to our ad hoc network.

It keeps on scanning at the wpa gui.

Can someone help us?

Comment: What USB adapter are you using ? What OS are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

I read on the Raspberry Pi website that you can create an adhoc from the Pi itself. That would be a more efficient proably. Here is the Link to the site: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=39927

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are using a different WiFi Adapter things will need adaptations. **Edimax 7811UN** doesn't support **Adhocing** past the kernel version of **3.9+**.

instead using **Ralink Technology based RT3570 Drivers** WiFi adapters will do the trip perfectly. 
For further insight I had post a query and resolved it for using Pis in Adhoc Fashion on [Stackoverflow Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157743/raspberry-pi-and-edimax-7811un-incompatibility-in-ad-hoc-mode/34458131#34458131)

Better to know what adapter you are working with!

Answer (score 0):

You can access your RPi from anywhere around the world if you use this:

[ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Quick steps to get you started:
(adapted from instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-online-SSH-easy-way/?ALLSTEPS)

```
sudo wget https://dl.ngrok.com/ngrok_2.0.19_linux_arm.zip
```

and then unzip it using:

```
unzip ngrok_2.0.19_linux_arm.zip
```

at ngrok website go to:

> dashboard.ngrok.com/user/login

and then click sign up to get an authtoken key. this token is necessary if you want your own custom domain doing an online SSH

after you manage to login you will get an authtoken key which a combination of a lot character.

You need to embed this token to your raspberry pi using:

```
./ngrok yourauthtoken
```

Now you can make your raspberry pi system to be controlled online using

```
./ngrok tcp 22
```

Using putty, enter the following IP address and port no:
[image]

By now you should be good to go!